# can't save video file in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have videostreams and I'd like to convert them to foreground detected videos on which everything is white that moving and all others are black.

When I run this below script nothing happens, python ide just waits. Should I wait, does the video render or do i make something wrong?

Thanks

```
import cv2
import numpy


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('2018_02_28_12_07_42.h264')
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

#while(cap.isOpened()):
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #if ret == True:
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('original', frame)
    cv2.imshow('fg', fgmask)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyWindows()
```

Comment: you can always put a `cv2.imshow("current", fgmask)` and `cv2.waitkey(10)` after the `out.write(fgmask)` command to see what is happening

Comment: Is it going inside the loop? write a print statement or an imshow()  inside the loop to see.

Comment: I just have a single frame, a static picture, when imshow which picture is not black but gray. What can be the mistake?

Comment: edited the original script, but when opening the output video I only have a black coloured image